# X Display not usabled after installation on PC

Tags: xorg, lightdm

I am setting up a PC with ubuntu. I have a problem with the graphical UI. The logon screen is displayed correctly. After logon another screen is displayed. But after half a second everything is blurred. It looks like there is problem with (horizontal) synchronization. But the mouse is displayed correctly!

When I switch from a text console to tty7 I can see again the screen for half a second.

- Ubuntu Release 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) 64-bit
- MATE 1.22.2
- uname -a `Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-46-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 27 17:37:05 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux"`
- display manager "lightdm"
- `xrandr` responses `Can't open display 127.0.0.10.0`
- There is no file /etc/X11/xorg.conf
- Running graphic driver is "nouveau"
- `lspci` outputs `VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Coporation NV43 [GeForce 6600] (rev a2)`
- Monitor is a Samsung S24C650
- Monitor shows `Analog, 67.5kHz 60Hz PP, 1920x1080`

The problem is independent on the used video cable, analog or DVI/HDMI. 
What can I do to troubleshoot and tell Ubuntu how to use my hardware correctly?

Comment: Providing the release of Ubuntu may help (that kernel is used by more than one release), but standard troubleshooting can be found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TroubleShootingGuide

Comment: Added Release number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to reduce the screen resolution that is chosen by the X11 server. This can be done by adding a file to

> /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Device"
  Identifier "Device0"
  Driver "nouveau"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Screen0"
  Device "Device0"
  Monitor "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1024x768"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

With this configuration I could start Display Preferences and configure different screen resolutions. The "best" resolution still leads to sync problems, but the OS is partially usable.